# Custom posts and get_post_meta in {$post_status}_{$post_type}

Tags: hooks, post-meta

I am making a function to parse a .csv file uploaded in a custom field of a custom post. The name of the custom **phone** and the field's name is **plan_information** . The problem is when I `var_dump(get_post_meta($post_id, 'plan_information', TRUE))` , I get an empty string. 
The code I use is the following:

```
add_action('publish_phone', 'parse_csv', '99', 2);

function parse_csv($post_id) {

global $post;

$csv_file = get_post_meta($post_id, 'plan_information', TRUE);

$csv_file = wp_get_attachment_url($csv_file);

$title = get_post_meta($post_id, 'manufacturer', TRUE);
$title .= ' '.get_post_meta($post_id, 'model', TRUE);
$title .= ' '.get_post_meta($post_id, 'memory', TRUE);

$url = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/';

$csv_file = str_replace($url, ABSPATH, $csv_file);

if($csv_file && !$carriers) {
    $fp = fopen($csv_file ,"r");
    if($fp) {
        fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

            $new_carrier = array(
                'post_title' => $title. ' '. $data[0] . ' ' . $data[3],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'carrier'
                );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_carrier);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'operator', $data[0], true);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'logo', $data[1], true);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'cost', $data[2], true);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'plan_name', $data[3], true);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'hero', $data[4], true);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'summary', $data[5], true);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'phone_id', $post_id, true);
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

}
```

Comment: What's the `publish_phone` hook? Have you checked that your function gets called?

Comment: It's this hook http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B$new_status%7D_%7B$post-%3Epost_type%7D . Yes if I die("test") it shows test on publish.

Comment: So the meta data is in the database? Does `$data` contain what you expect, and what does `add_post_meta` return?

Comment: I have fixed this using save_post action.

Comment: Post your code as an answer then please :). Also beware of infinite loops: `wp_insert_post` triggers `save_post`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to fix it, Thanks to Stephen Harris.

```
add_action('save_post', 'parse_csv', 10, 2);

function parse_csv($post_id) {

    $_pid = $post_id;
        // Autosave, do nothing
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
            return;
    // AJAX? Not used here
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) 
            return;
    // Check user permissions
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return;
    // Return if it's a post revision
    if ( false !== wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
            return;
    if('phone' == $_POST['post_type']) {

        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

        $csv_file = get_post_meta($post_id, 'plan_information', TRUE);
        $csv_file = wp_get_attachment_url($csv_file);
        $title = get_post_meta($post_id, 'manufacturer', TRUE). ' '.get_post_meta($post_id, 'model', TRUE).' '.get_post_meta($post_id, 'memory', TRUE);
        $url = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/';

        $csv_file = str_replace($url, ABSPATH, $csv_file);

        $carriers = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'carrier', 'meta_key' => 'phone_id', 'meta_value' => $_pid));

        update_post_meta($_pid, "_wp_page_template", "phone-page.php");

        if($csv_file && !$carriers) {
            $fp = fopen($csv_file,"r");
            if($fp) {
                fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",");

                while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {

                    $new_carrier = array(
                        'post_title' => $title . '-' .$data[3],
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'post_type' => 'carrier'
                        );

                    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_carrier);
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'operator', $data[0], true);
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'logo', $data[1], true);
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'cost', $data[2], true);
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'plan_name', $data[3], true);
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'hero', $data[4], true);
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'summary', $data[5], true);
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'phone_id', $_pid, true);
                }

                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
    }

}
```